# Algorithm for Minimum Diameter Spanning Tree

Tags: tag-removed

Given a undirected and connected graph G, find a spanning tree whose diameter is the minimum.
How to solve this problem

Comment: Question? Motivation?

Comment: Voting to close: see our FAQ and http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="minimum+diameter+spanning+tree"

Comment: This a question

Comment: Have you tried [a search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Minimum+Diameter+Spanning+Tree)? Wasn't the results satisfactory? What you found up until now? These are the elements that make a question worth answering.

Comment: @Sadeq Dousti: The link you should be suggesting is [here](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=minimum+diameter+spanning+tree).  If satisfactory answers aren't on StackExchange (even if they're easy to find on Google), then a question is fair to ask.  Currently, the top result is this one (closed as off-topic), and the second-to-top result just links to Google Docs.  Read/listen to [StackOverflow Podcast #58](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4148.html) for Joel Spolsky's take on the issue.

Comment: @Joey Adams: According to *our* FAQ the OP should do *their part* by attempting to answer their questions by *themselves* before asking them here, and that includes Googling. See the meta discussion on how to ask a good question. @Rambo: Your question can be reopened if you improve it, e.g. tell us why you care, what you have done to find an answer, and what is the best thing you have found, and why that does not solve your problem.

Comment: I agree to Kaveh.  [Here is a link to the Meta discussion on how to ask a good question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question).